# Select radio button on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select a radio button on click with jQuery. I can't seem to get this to work though. Here is my current attempt.

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#payment").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $("input:radio[name=slug_tier_1]").attr("checked", true)
  })
});
```

## HTML

```
  <label class="plans__tier-1__actions">
    <%= radio_button_tag "slug", "tier_1", required: true %>
    <a href="#" class="button" id="payment">Select</a>
  </label>
```

## Screenshot of name

[image]
This seems as though it should work? Any thing jump out at you?

Comment: Its working fine, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/gw7vfrnf/

Comment: You should work with the property method, `prop`, and not the attribute method, `attr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input[type='radio'][name='slug_tier_1']").attr("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="slug_tier_1">
```

If the name of the input is the same in the rendered HTML, the selector should be

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='slug_tier_1']").attr("checked", true);
```

The type should be given like any other attribute in `[]`.Also the name should be enclosed in quotes. See [link](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

From RoR [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag)

```
radio_button_tag 'gender', 'male'
# => <input id="gender_male" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" />
```

So in this case the name should be just `slug`. `slug_tier_1` is the ID of the element.

Either try

```
$("input[type='radio'][id='slug_tier_1']").attr("checked", true);
```

Or

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='slug']").attr("checked", true);
```

Comment: What the heck an doing wrong? You're right but that still doesn't select the radio button. This is frustrating.

Comment: Edited my answer. Type `radio` should be given like any other attribute.

Comment: Check the name in the rendered HTML. Is it the same.

Comment: `radio_button_tag 'gender', 'male'`
`# => <input id="gender_male" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" />`. So in this case name should be just `slug`

Comment: ID and Name are different. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="btn">button</a>
<input type="radio" class="radio">

$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(".radio").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: I know what I'm doing wrong becuase that still doesn't work?? I'm using turbolinks

Comment: Make sure query is loaded properly check console in chrome (f12) for javascript errors

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Try this and check in console. There might be multiple elements of same ids

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("#payment"));
  $("#payment").click(function(event) {
    console.log($("input:radio[name=slug_tier_1]"));
  })
});
```

Check if it returns a single element or multiple elements for both `#payment` or `$("input:radio[name=slug_tier_1]")`

Try and Reply